# Array or someother collection where i can store multiple types

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of information that I need to store in some kind of collection, the problem is that i am not allowed to create a separate class for it because they say "i could mess up the structure and design of other things" so I have an integer and a string and what I want to do is to be able to store them like this

```
 index or similar   int           string

       index[0]          | 1 | "Bear, Person, Bird"|
       index[1]          | 2 | "Pear, Apples, Lime"|
```

The question is, is there a collection of some type for which I can store data like this without the need of a class so that i can reference it like this

```
myWeirdList.add(2,"Test, test, Test, test");
```

or

```
myWeirdArray.add(3,"roco,paco");
```

I hope the questions is clear if not I will keep an eye to better clarify..

Comment: If you're using C# 4.0, you can check out the [Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

Comment: Have you had a look at a Dictionary? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: Wow guys really interesting concepts...

Comment: Agree with Tim - array of `Tuple<int, string>` should do the trick!

Comment: I think "they" introduce even more trouble by not using a custom class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as Tim said for .net 4.0 there are Tuples:

```
var myTupleList = new List<Tuple<int, string>();
myTupleList.Add(Tuple.Create(2, "Test, test, Test, test");
```

if not you can allways use just object and box:

```
var myObjList = new ArrayList();
myObjList.Add(2);
myObjList.Add("Test, test, Test, test");
```

And if all other fails just make a private struct yourself  - I just don't know how you could mess up some other design with this.

Comment: One question, so if I need to pass this to a property (the items), what should the property type be? List or Tuple?.. if i understand correctly..

Comment: if you want the Tuple-List than your type would have to be *List<Tuple<int, string>>*

Answer (score 2):

You could use either object or dynamic if you're using .Net 4.0.

Alternatively you might consider using an array of Dictionary items where an array entry is of type `<int, string>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Create a new dictionary
Dictionary<int,string> myWeirdList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

// Add items to it
myWeirdList.Add(2, "Test, test, Test, test");

// Retrieve text using key
var text_using_key = myWeirdList[2];

// Retrieve text using index
var text_using_index = myWeirdList.ElementAt(0).Value;
```